# .NET: How to sort a Generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Dictionary:
`Dictionary<string, CustomClass> _details = new Dictionary<string, CustomClass>()`

`CustomClass` implements `IComparable` as there is custom sort logic in the `CompareTo()` method.

I want to loop through all my `CustomClass`'s in _details in a sorted order.

So I want to do something like this:

```
foreach (string value in _details.Values.Sort())
{

}
```

But `Sort()` isn't a method on that type

What are my options here?

Comment: Did you mean *non-generic* in your question title?

Comment: Did you want to sort by keys or values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but on rereading it *appears* that you want to order by value rather than key. In that case, LINQ is the best approach with the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343617.aspx) method:

```
foreach (var pair in _details.OrderBy(p => p.Value))
{
    // Use pair.Key and pair.Value here
}
```

Or if you only want the values in the first place:

```
foreach (var value in _details.Values.OrderBy(p => p))
{
    // Use value in here
}
```

Note that you can't sort a dictionary in-place - `Dictionary<,>` is fundamentally unordered (or rather, the order is an implementation detail, and cannot be changed in a reliable manner).

If you wanted to sort by *key*, it would probably be better to use [`SortedList<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) to start with. Both of these will keep the collection sorted by key permanently.

Comment: He seems to want to order by the values and not by the keys. But possibly he mixed something up with keys and values and really wants `CustomClass` as key.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It's not clear whether he wants to *order* by the values, or whether he wants the *values*, but ordered by key. EDIT: Oops, just seen that CustomClass implements IComparable, so presumably it really is by value. Editing...

Comment: Yes I want to order by the Values NOT the keys. I want to loop through the Values in a sorted order AND I want the sorting to be done using the IComparable.CompareTo() method in CustomClass as there is a lot of sorting logic i.e. an OrderBy will not suffice

Comment: @Bob: In what way will OrderBy not suffice? It will use your custom comparison automatically - we're ordering *by* the `CustomClass`, i.e. comparing CustomClass values against each other.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that OrderBy would do the trick ... i'll give it a go thanks

Answer (score 8):

Linq offers a `OrderBy` method on all enumerables. It creates a copy on each call and does not modify the original collection.

Your code piece: `string key in _details.Values` doesn't make any sense. `Values` contains the values and not the keys. I assume you want to iterate over the key value pairs, i.e.
    foreach(var pair in _details.OrderBy(pair=>pair.Value))

If you want to discard the value after using it for sorting you can add a `.Select(pair=>pair.Key)`. If you're only interested in the values it's even simpler:

```
foreach(var value in _details.OrderBy(v=>v))
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for confusing, I want to order by the Values NOT the keys, I corrected the question text.